# Как не вызывать функцию типа char при ёё присваивании в переменную типа char

Tags: c++

```
strcpy_s(inputOperator,strlen(ChooseOperator())+1,ChooseOperator());
```

Когда я выполняю этот код у меня функция ChooseOperator() вызывается 2 раза
inputOperator - `char inputOperator[32];`
Вопрос:как этого избежать

Comment: ну так очевидно - `const char* foo = ChooseOperator(); strcpy_s(inputOperator,strlen(foo)+1,foo);`,

Comment: вторым аргументом `strcpy_s` должен быть размер массива, на который указывает первый аргумент, то бишь `strcpy_s(inputOperator, ::std::size(inputOperator),ChooseOperator());`

Comment: @user7860670, Скорее второй аргумент  ,  не должен быть  размером целевого массива, а просто является количеством копируемых символов из копируемого  массива  и  должен быть не больше размера  целевого массива. А ответ на вопрос как не вызывать  функцию типа char очень прост: такого типа функций не может быть, потому никак не вызовите

Answer (score 2):

Правильный код такой:

```
strcpy_s(inputOperator, ::std::size(inputOperator), ChooseOperator());
```

Из [документации](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) про второй параметр `strcpy_s`:

> destsz    -   maximum number of characters to write, typically the size
> of the destination buffer

Идея в том чтобы первые два параметра на зависили от строки которую мы копируем. Сравните:

```
strcpy_s(dst, sizeof(src), src);      // 1
strcpy_s(dst, strlen(src) + 1, src);  // 2

strcpy_s(dst, sizeof(dst), src);      // 3
```

Если в первом и вторых вариантах `src` слишком велик, вы пишете в память за концом `dst`. Возникает неопределённое поведение. Программа продолжает работу, что опасно.

Напротив, в третьем варианте, функция обнаружит ошибку и прервёт программу, чтобы предотвратить распространение ошибки. Также будут перехвачены многие другие ошибки.

Не пользуйтесь первым и вторым способми, вы теряете возможность обнаружить ошибку.

**P.S.** Для полноты как можно было бы поправить ваш код:

```
const char *op = ChooseOperator();
strcpy_s(inputOperator, strlen(op) + 1, op);
```

Comment: @user7860670, был код совместимый с C, а стал только C++.

Comment: Ну так С в вопросе и не упоминается. А для совместимости с С следовало бы использовать макрос типа  ARRAY_SIZE

Comment: Чем плох sizeof?

Comment: Ну как же, попытка получения количества элементов в буфере посредством sizeof - типичнейшая ошибка у новичков.

Comment: Явный тип в вопросе: `char inputOperator[32]`. Кроме того случайное уменьшение размера до 8 байт не приведёт к катастрофе: код будет падать с очевидной ошибкой.

Comment: Сегодня это `char inputOperator[32]`, а завтра обязательно кто-то скопипастит этот кусок себе у него внезапно исходный размер массива например 5 сможет *увеличится* до 8. Или кто-то скопипастит его себе подправив на вызов для wchar_t. И размер массива внезапно станет в два раза больше.